# Wordpress echo text from wordpress text-editor to a div-box on a pages

Tags: php, wordpress, editor

i just maid my own wordpress theme.... 
when i add some text to at specific pages in the editor it won't show on the page??

should i add a have_post code to the template?? 
i have tried to search the web for info, and tried different stuff...

here is my code for the template:

```
<?php

/*
Template Name: Kategori
*/

 ?>

<?php get_header(); the_post();?>
                <!--        main page start  -->
<div class="main">




</div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

anyone know why??

Answer (score 0):

You are missing The Loop. Here is a very stripped down version of a page template that should work.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages
 */
get_header(); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="primary">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div><!-- #primary -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

When inside The Loop, you would use the_content() to call whatever is entered into the WYSIWYG editor for the page.

If you are outside of The Loop, you would do this:

```
<?php echo get_the_content($pageID); ?>
```

The variable $pageID would be set to whatever the ID of the page you are trying to pull from.